# Is a question about the working conditions in countries I don't live in on-topic?

Tags: discussion

I live in Israel. Here if an employee is working on a holiday or on Saturday (the vacation day) they are paid a double salary by law. There is the recent issue of US retail stores opening on Thanksgiving and many sources claim that it's not fair to the employees. I wanted to know whether an employee who works on a federal holiday in the US is payed more. I couldn't find any sources on the Internet on this, and this is the most closely related site to the issue on the SE network.

Is the question about whether or not employees in the US get paid more for working on holidays on topic here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not ask this on [workplace.stackexchange.com](http://workplace.stackexchange.com)?  Employment law and holidays are totally on topic there...

Comment: you meant http://workplace.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 9):

Not really, it's not a travel question, it's an employment law question and/or working question.  Unfortunately just because it's the 'closest' on the SE network doesn't mean they have a site suitable for it ... yet. You can always propose a new site for the network! :)

Comment: You might give [quora](http://www.quora.com) a try - they accept all topics and have a vaguely similar approach to Stack Exchange in other respects.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it'd be on-topic here.

Maybe see if politics stack exchange would be a better fit for this question.

Answer (score 1):

It might be on topic if it were cast as a travel question: I'm going to New York City. What stores/chains should I avoid patronizing there because I'm concerned about companies that don't pay overtime to their workers?